# Problem attaching class to movie clip in actionscript at depth 30

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, movieclip, actionscript-2

I have a number pad component in as2. This component has buttons for 0-9. All of them are separate movie clips with code attached that allows them to act as a button. Each state of the button (up,pressed,unavailable) are different keyframes and gotoandstop is used to set the state.
My problem is that the numpad button at depth 30 constantly play as if the class attached to that symbol can not be found. If I right click on that symbol and select send backwards it works and the button next to it fails. I have bumped the data from the swf and I can set that whichever button is at depth 30 is the one that fails. Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: There probably is a conflict with some other object at the same depth and/or with the same name. But we can't really tell, unless you provide some of your code.  Generally, it is advisable to work with getNextHighestDepth() or your own depth counter, so you won't have to worry about assigning two instances to the same depth.

Comment: All of my objects have been placed in CS4, so they should be on different depths. When I run a swf dump I can search for 030 and see that only one object is on depth 30. If I right click on the object and send it backwards the next button fails and a search on a swfdump from this version shows that the new failing button is now at depth 30. There is only one object at that depth.

Comment: I noticed another peculiarity. So I duplicated the numpad objects and attached the class and named this duplicate of numpad button hack. What I noticed is that now the object at depth 33 is the one that is failing. The depths for all my numpad buttons are 3 depths apart due to each object containing several sub-objects. It now appears the the button at the penultimate depth is the one that breaks. When the highest depth was 33 the button at depth 30 breaks. Now that I've added a new button the highest depth is 36 and the button at depth 33 is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a compilation failure that kept the class definition from attaching to the movie clip. It's weird that this only happened to the one clip, especially since the class that was failing wasn't the class I was attaching anyways. I'm guessing it a timing issue, or something similar. Either way It works now.